# Selenium is not finding button even though it has a Class Name and XPath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, xpath

I am attempting to click a save button but Selenium (with Python) is having issues. I keep getting the error, "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="action[save]" class="FixedRight SPSubmitRequest button save-button disabledsubmit" value="Save">
```

And the XPath

```
//*[@id="spsisFunctionJSAutoFormID12"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input
```

I have attempted the following to no avail

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="spsisFunctionJSAutoFormID12"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input').click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name('FixedRight SPSubmitRequest button save-button disabledsubmit" value').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@name='Save'].click()
```

None of these work and all produce the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="spsisFunctionJSAutoFormID12"]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/input').click()
```

Without the rest of the DOM it's hard to tell what might be wrong with this one.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('FixedRight SPSubmitRequest button save-button disabledsubmit" value').click()
```

You accidentally copy+pasted in `" value`.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@name='Save'].click()
```

According to your snippet, the name is `action[save]` and the quotes are slightly off.

Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@value="Save"]').click();`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! So it ended up being that the class name was hidden for some reason.

Comment: //button[@value="Save"] this wouldn't work because the web element is an input tag and not a button.

Comment: Change button to the appropriate tagName or use the * wild card.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with these 2 statements in Selenium + Java and they worked as expected:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='action[save]']")).isDisplayed());

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class='FixedRight SPSubmitRequest button save-button disabledsubmit']")).isDisplayed());
```

You can change the syntax to Python. It may be something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='action[save]']").click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class='FixedRight SPSubmitRequest button save-button disabledsubmit']").click()
```

Answer (score -1):

In outsourced qa testing we can create multiple type of locators for this element using attribute, css and xpaths. One of the most effective method using xpath for locating the element is using value i.e
//input[@value='Save']. For xpath cheat sheet please refer the below link for more details to create effective xpaths https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/most-exhaustive-xpath-locators-cheat-sheet/.